# Using interp2 in Matlab with NaN inputs

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have some observational data that is relatively complete, but contains some NaN values, in an matrix in `matlab` and I want to interpolate them to a more evenly spaced grid using `interp2`

So, to keep things simple lets say I have one complete (no NaN values) matrix, and one that looks something like:

```
A = [ 1  2  3  4;
      2  3  2 NaN;
      0  2  3  4;
      0 NaN 4  5  ]
```

with `B` and `C` being complete matrices, `interp2` won't accept an input matrix with NaN values. So if I do something like this:

```
[AI,BI] = meshgrid(a,b) %# matrices to interpolate data to, arbitrary
CI = interp2(A,B,C,AI,BI) %# interpolation, A has NaN values
```

I get an error:

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
The coordinates of the input points must be finite values; Inf and NaN are not permitted.
```

Can anyone suggest either a solution, or reasonable work around that doesn't obstruct my data?

Comment: Just avoid the point containing `NaN`s. Something like: `idxgood=~(isnan(A) | isnan(B) | isnan(C)); CI = interp2(A(idxgood),B(idxgood),C(idxgood),AI,BI)`

Comment: You should make that an answer. I do that all the time.

Comment: `interp2` is not suitable for this situation since  it is for gridded data. And `griddata` is for scattered data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry the quick fix I gave in comment does not work directly for 2D data (*it does work that simply with* `interp1` *though, if you ever need it*).

For gridded data, if you have `NaN`s in your grid then you do not have a uniform grid and you cannot use `interp2` directly. In this case you have to use [`griddata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) first, to re-interpolate your data over a uniform grid (patch the holes basically).

(1) Let's show an example inspired from the Matlab doc:

```
%% // define a surface
[A,B] = meshgrid(-3:0.25:3);
C = peaks(A,B);

%// poke some holes in it (in every coordinate set)
A(15,3:8)   = NaN ;
B(14:18,13) = NaN ;
C(8,16:21)  = NaN ;
```

[image: grid hole]

(2) Now let's fix your data on a clean grid:

```
%// identify indices valid for the 3 matrix 
idxgood=~(isnan(A) | isnan(B) | isnan(C)); 

%// define a "uniform" grid without holes (same boundaries and sampling than original grid)
[AI,BI] = meshgrid(-3:0.25:3) ;

%// re-interpolate scattered data (only valid indices) over the "uniform" grid
CI = griddata( A(idxgood),B(idxgood),C(idxgood), AI, BI ) ;
```

[image: fixed grid]

(3) Once your grid is uniform, you can then use `interp2` if you want to mesh on a finer grid for example:

```
[XI,YI] = meshgrid(-3:0.1:3) ;   %// create finer grid
ZI = interp2( AI,BI,CI,XI,YI ) ; %// re-interpolate
```

[image: finer grid]

---

However, note that if this is all what you wanted to do, you could also use `griddata` only, and do everything in one step:

```
%// identify indices valid for the 3 matrix 
idxgood=~(isnan(A) | isnan(B) | isnan(C)); 

%// define a "uniform" grid without holes (finer grid than original grid)
[XI,YI] = meshgrid(-3:0.1:3) ;

%// re-interpolate scattered data (only valid indices) over the "uniform" grid
ZI = griddata( A(idxgood),B(idxgood),C(idxgood), XI, YI ) ;
```

This produces the exact same grid and data than we obtained on step (3) above.

---

Last note: In case your `NaN`s are on the border of your domain, by default these functions cannot "interpolate" values for these border. To force them to do so, look at the `extrapolation` options of these functions, or simply interpolate on a slightly smaller grid which doesn't have `NaN` on the border.

Comment: Great answer, using `griddata` in one step works great for me.