# Smooth data and graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a small MATLAB (R2010a) script that imports a data file of temperatures and plots them as a surface graph representing points along a ceramic tube.

```
raw = importdata('C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\EMP\LabJack\He_Test_7-29\SiMgO_8-1.dat');
temps = raw(:,[9 3:8]);
time = round((raw(:,1) - 3552917232.273) * 10.^1) / 10.^1;

x = (0:41)*0.0254;    % Record the x scale for tube plots
tempplot = zeros(length(time),size(x,2));
tempplot(:,:) = 27;
tempplot(:,end) = temps(:,1);

for n = 1:3
    tempplot(:,2+2*n) = temps(:,8-n);
    tempplot(:,31+2*n) = temps(:,5-n);
end

for t = 1:length(time)*.01
    timeplot(t) = transpose(time(t)) / 36;
end

%* Plot tube temperature versus x and t as wire-mesh and contour plots
tempplot = tempplot(1:100:end-74,:);
figure(3); clf;
surf(timeplot,x,transpose(tempplot));   % Wire-mesh surface plot
shading interp
xlabel('Time (hours)'); ylabel('x (meters)'); zlabel('T(x,t) (C)');
title('Diffusion of temp along mullite tube (experimental)');
```

Here's an example of the data being imported:

```
3552917232.273000   299.745906  27.491608   27.463276   27.420625   27.173824   27.198507   26.933061   26.944948
3552917233.274000   299.745906  27.462362   27.484601   27.421235   27.185099   27.221056   26.945863   26.965064
3552917234.274000   299.745906  27.476376   27.473025   27.413009   27.196069   27.218923   26.935195   26.967503
3552917235.276000   299.745906  27.490390   27.460535   27.403869   27.203382   27.231721   26.967198   26.948606
```

The first column is the time and the second is a cold-junction control temp. I am mostly interested in the time and remaining temperature values in columns 3-9, though they are re-ordered in the script to match their placement along the tube. The script creates a nice graph already:
[image]

But what I really would like is a smoothing of the data to fill the gaps in the graphs peaks. I thought interp1 or interp2 would be able to accomplish this, but I'm not able to figure it out so far. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**
Per excaza's request:
I've played around with interp2 such as

```
y = interp2(tempplot)
```

or

```
y = interp2(x,timeplot,tempplot,xi,yi)
```

but I don't understand how the xi and yi are used in this function.

**Edit2:**
In response to rayryeng's marking this as a duplicate question, here is a more thorough example of what happens when I use interp2:

```
[x1,y1] = meshgrid(1:size(tempplot,2),1:size(tempplot,1));
[x2,y2] = meshgrid(1:.5:size(tempplot,2),1:.5:size(tempplot,1));
refined = interp2(x1,y1,tempplot,x2,y2,'linear');
surf(refined)
```

The result:
[image]

As you can see, there are still gaps between the peaks.

**Edit3:**
I have somewhat solved the issue by adding the following between the existing for loops:

```
refined = zeros(size(tempplot));
refined(:,:) = 27;
for step = 1:size(temps,1)
    refined(step,:) = smooth(tempplot(step,:),'lowess');
end
```

Then I plot the 'refined' matrix instead of 'tempplot'.
[image]

While it's not perfectly smooth, it is a start.

Comment: `interp2` should do the trick, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also: DO NOT USE THE JET COLOMAP! ITS THE DEVIL!

Comment: @AnderBiguri They're using R2010a. `jet` is unfortunately non-negotiable :(

Comment: @rayryeng YES NEGOTIABLE! They can use `hot` or just download another colormap!

Comment: @AnderBiguri `hot` is even uglier!... but you are right. They can download the `parula` colour map themselves. I did that for R2013a when I had it.

Comment: @rayryeng ahhhh but its not uglyness the (only) problem! Its the perceptual change in color vs data!

Comment: I've played around with interp2 such as `y = interp2(tempplot)` or `y = interp2(x,timeplot,tempplot,xi,yi)`, but I don't understand how the xi and yi are used in this function.

Comment: @razzle_dazzle_84 please [edit] code into your question, do not post it in the comments.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for `interp2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html)? There are many examples.

Comment: Yes, I have - extensively. And I have searched this site and the Internet in general for additional examples. I'm only posting this question because I have not been able to solve the problem myself.

Comment: Use the marked duplicate, but instead of using `imagesc` as the command for visualization,  use `surf`. The duplicate shows you how to use `interp2` to create a "smooth" plot.

Comment: Or use [`griddata`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html), as shown in this answer : [Interpolation between two curves (matlab)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494254/interpolation-between-two-curves-matlab/23497688#23497688). This other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729855/using-interp2-in-matlab-with-nan-inputs/31743316#31743316) is less directly relevant but has more examples on how to control the base grid for interpolation.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles across this post in the future, I was finally able to solve the issue myself after playing around with the curve fitting tool. Since this post was (IMO erroneously) marked as a duplicate, I will post my solution in this comment:
`smooth = zeros(size(tempplot));
for o = 1:length(tempplot)
    slice = tempplot(o,:);
    f = fit(x,slice.','smoothingspline','Normalize','on','Exclude',slice<=25);
    smooth(o,:) = f(x).';
end`