# How does a smaller surface squares in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, grid, mesh, surface

I want to make the grid of the smaller mesh, some idea of how it is done?
That is to say something like that the path in the x-axis and y are 0.25 in 0.25,

```
x = (0: 0.25: 7);
y = (0: 0.25: 7);
```

I've the following matrix. This matrix modeling the dynamic of a population (projection matrix)

```
L2=[0 0 0 0 127 4 80;
    0.6747 0.7370 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0.0486 0.6610 0 0 0 0; 
    0 0 0.0147 0.6907 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0.0518 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0.8091 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0.8091 0.8089];
```

With this code, I find the eingenvectors rigth and left of L2. Likewise I find the sensivity and elasticity matrix.

```
A=L2;
[W,lambdas]=eig(A);
V=conj(inv(W));
lambdas=diag(lambdas);
[lambdas,I]=sort(lambdas);
lambdas=flipud(lambdas);
lambda1=lambdas(1);
I=flipud(I);
W=W(:,I);
V=V(I,:);
w=W(:,1);
w=w/sum(w);
v=real(V(1,:))';
v=v/v(1);
% matrix of sensitivity
senmat=v*w';
% matrix of elasticity
emat=senmat.*A/max(eig(A));
```

Then, I make a surface of sensivity matrix.

```
surf(senmat)
```

This is the result:
[image: This is a surface of the matrix of sensitivity]

I need to make the squares (grid) of the surface smaller.

any ideas?

best regards!

Comment: The function [`griddata`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) is your friend ;-) ... and if you want some example on how to use it, check this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729855/using-interp2-in-matlab-with-nan-inputs/31743316#31743316)

Comment: Hi @Hoki Thanks for your help! It was very useful to consult your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can use interp2 if you have (x,y) which are defined for senmat. Read about interp2. If you want only senmat to refine use imresize.

```
A = imresize(senmat,[100,100]) ;
surf(A)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Siva Srinivas Kolukula I don't have read about interp2. Since I just wanted to redefine the size of the grids, your suggestion was useful. I used imresize! Thanks!